# How do I add Buttons in Discord Python?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I looked up for many Tutorials for adding a button to discord Python. But they were outdated.

Are there any solutions for that so that I could continue building my bot? and could someone help me with adding a button?

I would like to see a response.

I am using PyCharm.

I tried what most of the tutorials said, but they didn't work, so I thought of looking for more but they were all outdated.

Comment: You want to build a desktop application using python? Look at tkinter, PyQt, Kivy, PySimpleGUI, ...

Comment: Pretty sure they mean an interaction button for a discord message using a python bot

Comment: @tobifasc I do not want to build a desktop application but a Discord Bot, so i need help with creating a button.